# If I have multiple threads in my program, does each thread technically have it's own stack? Does each thread have it's own heap?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been trying to find the answer to this question in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) (and with Google) but I am not able to find anything that directly discusses the state of the call stack and heap in a multi-threaded program.

Also, does a synchronised object get flip flopped between both stacks (assuming they are seperate stacks)

Comment: Own stack, shared heap.

Comment: Thank you. Please see my synchronisation question.

Comment: Stack maintains references, if thread 1 executing synchronized part, threa2 will be kept in waiting.

Comment: @Nambari - Not unless the code explicitly requests synchronization.  And even then it's a very complex topic.

Comment: Objects only really exist in the shared heap.  A synchronized object is on the heap and stays there.  Don't forget the stack only has primitives and references.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes, assuming code explicitly requests synchronization.

Comment: Thanks guys, I feel that I have a lot better grasp on multithreading now.

Comment: FYI: Java objects are only created in the heap.  Unlike C++, you will never find a Java object on any thread's stack.  The stack holds the arguments and local variables of each active function along with information about where to return to when the function returns.  Arguments and local variables in Java never hold objects:  They either hold _references_ (a.k.a., "pointers") to objects, or they hold primitive values (int, double, boolean, char, ...).

Comment: Sorry to ask another question, but a friend of mine, who is a professional java developer, told me ( when i asked her the above question) that the stack or stacks, in this case, is actually contained WITHIN the heap. I don't think this is true based on my research. It's she correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They share the heap, but each thread has its own stack (otherwise it wouldn't know what it's executing).

Nothing is flip flopped (I don't understand why you think that would happen). Objects can't be synchronized, only code is synchronized (by acquiring an object's monitor or lock).

Comment: Thank god for your sir. I couldn't get a straight answer on this anywhere. Also, I updated my question, please have a look. I will accept as soon as I am able.

Comment: Synchronization is a complex topic.  Not something that can be understood and appreciated in a few minutes .... or hours .... or days.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple threads in Java share the same heap space. Each thread gets its own stack.

The Java Virtual Machine is stacked based. In pseudocode an add instruction may look like this.

```
push 2 //Stack: 2
push 3 //Stack: 2,3
add    //Stack: 5
```

If threads shared the same address space then it may turn into something weird since they share the same stack. When they start popping off values from other threads the virtual machine will do strange things and may crash.

Here is what it might look like if we did that same example above on two threads.(This is just a possible way the stack might look like.)

```
Thread 1               Thread 2
push 2 //Stack: 2    : push 2 //Stack: 2,2
push 3 //Stack: 2,2,3: push 3 //Stack: 2,2,3,3
add //Stack 2,2,6    : add //Stack 2,8
```

You can easily see that if they shared the same stack, things would get corrupt fast.